# Flag declined for now-deleted question - how should I have flagged it (or should I have not flagged it at all)?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

My question is for clarification on when a post is beyond off-topic into borderline crazy, but not quite to the point of rudeness. Is that still just “off-topic”?

I've a question about a now-deleted question that I flagged, titled [***"Wordpress monopoly and suppression of feedback and unethical practices"***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63608909/wordpress-monopoly-and-suppression-of-feedback-and-unethical-practices)

The "question" was a huge rant (so long it got truncated) about the Wordpress organisation, how the user was banned, why it wasn't their fault, etc.

I felt it needed more than just a close vote so I flagged it as "*in need of moderation intervention*", but the flag was declined with a message about using standard flags. However was since deleted "*for reasons of moderation*" so I am just wondering:

Clearly the post wasn't suitable as it was removed, so was I correct to flag it except my flag reason wasn't good enough? Or was it removed for some other reason and I was wrong to flag it?

To be honest I'd no idea how to describe it so I my reason might have been weak, but I thought when combined with the title it would be reason enough to look into it. I said it was "a very long rant against the Wordpress organisation, I'm not sure what the purpose is but it doesn't seem to belong here or have any value for SO.*".

I just want to be clear about how to handle situations like this, so I know what to do if I see another unsuitable post like this in future!

Comment: _"huge rant"_ is understatement of the day.

Comment: You need a bit more specific what you want the mod to do. *can you check if this user has a history of similar posts that warrants more action then just down, close and delete voting.* might have been enough to lure Martijn into marking that flag helpful.

Comment: @gnat, I understand not to flag for off-topic, but this was way beyond off-topic and was borderline crazy - it was a full page rant complaining about another organisation. My questions is how to handle a question that is way past off-topic but not quite to the point rudeness. Is that still just “off topic”?

Comment: Close-vote it unless it's abusive. Don't worry, it will be deleted eventually, no need to bother mods.

Comment: I feel your pain. When I see questions like you describe I myself am _heavily_ tempted to flag. However, at SO, things works in such a way that question mod flags are expected to be handled only if there is an authoritative reference that moderator involvement is justified for particular case. This is a matter of scale - if we wanted moderators to handle all such questions we'd need much more of them - like, an order of hundreds mods. (I noticed that you have accounts at some smaller sites - these things tend to work very differently over there because of much smaller size)